# Fetching global api data in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm starting Nuxt project and I have to fetch basic data from my backend.
for example language dictionary or some data for leftbar and etc.
in Vue I can just call everything I need in App.vue and save it in vuex and then use whenever I want, but with Nuxt every page is different and I'm curious where should i call this global data api calls.
I'm guessing I have to create middleware and call actions if data is not loaded already or there is better solution?

Comment: Yes, i'm using universal mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention it's global data and you're using universal mode- I think you're looking for `nuxtServerInit()`. This store action runs once on the server, before `created`, `mounted` hooks etc. You can use it to populate your store with data that your components (including pages) rely on.

Take a look at the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action).

```
actions: {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    if (req.session.user) {
      commit('user', req.session.user)
    }
  }
}
```